# React native debugger: "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory"

Tags: typescript, react-native, metro-bundler

**Problem:** When I run the remote debugger, metro server says it can't find this file.

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/hery/Workspace/NyTiona/http:/localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.nytiona&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:498:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:394:35)
    at getCodeFrame (/home/hery/Workspace/NyTiona/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:919:18)
    at Server._symbolicate (/home/hery/Workspace/NyTiona/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:992:22)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async Server._processRequest (/home/hery/Workspace/NyTiona/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:403:7) {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '/home/hery/Workspace/NyTiona/http:/localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.nytiona&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true'
}
```

**Note:**  This error always appears whether I am using USB or Wi-Fi.

**info:**  My react native info

```
    System:
    OS: Linux 5.4 Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa)
    CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4200U CPU @ 1.60GHz
    Memory: 1.51 GB / 7.49 GB
    Shell: 5.0.17 - /bin/bash
  Binaries:
    Node: 14.17.2 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: Not Found
    npm: 6.14.13 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/bin/watchman
  SDKs:
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 30
      Build Tools: 30.0.2, 30.0.3, 31.0.0
      System Images: android-30 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom
      Android NDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 4.2 AI-202.7660.26.42.7486908
  Languages:
    Java: 1.8.0_292 - /usr/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 17.0.2 => 17.0.2 
    react-native: 0.65.1 => 0.65.1 
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same problem and just did,

```js
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

solved my problem.

Comment: I tested it but the error still appears

Comment: have you tried deleting your `node_modules` and run `npm install` again after that?

Comment: It doesn't work yet. I think the error is due to this url with the absolute path.

`/home/hery/Workspace/NyTiona/http:/localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.nytiona&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true`

-- 
Because  -- `http:/localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.nytiona&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true` does exist if I look for it on the browser

Comment: This could be an error if there is a metro server open with another project. try closing that metro server tab and run again.

Comment: Resetting metro cache worked for me!

Comment: @Hery - did you ever find something that works?

Comment: @DonBranson Not for the moment. It's really frustrating

Comment: Any solution? Its been a while

Comment: @Hery did you find the root cause?

Answer (score -4):

Based on Shoaib Khan anwser, I managed to solve the problem by opening two terminals, one with the command below:

```
npx react-native start "--reset-cache"
```

And in the other terminal, just bring android up:

```
npx react-native run-android
```

> Dont forget deleting `node_modules` directory to reinstall them by running `npm install`.