# react-native metro crashes when starting app after installing react-native-mmkv

Tags: reactjs, react-native, metro-bundler

I just installed react-native-mmkv and when I start my app my metro crashes with the following error:

```
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'E:\Dokumente\GitHub\WorkoutPlanner\WorkoutPlanner\node_modules\react-native-mmkv\android\build\intermediates\cxx\Debug\1c3k3h4l\obj\armeabi-v7a\libreactnativemmkv.so.tmpfd97190
```

If I re-run the metro while the appis starting, everything works fine. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by creating a whole new project and copying my whole code, installing all the dependencies again. After installing react-native-mmkv I got another error, but i fixed it by starting my bundler with

```
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69387345/react-native-debugger-error-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory)